# insert identity table column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have table propertybag, it's have only one identity coloumn

fo eg

```
   propertybagid identity(1,1)
```

i want to insert this value to this column one by one by query how?

plz reply soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Insert into propertybagid default values
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT T DEFAULT VALUES
```

Or to insert multiple rows (up to 2048 at a time using the spt_values table)

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT t ON
INSERT INTO t (id) 
SELECT Number + COALESCE(IDENT_CURRENT('t'),0) + 1
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
where type='p' and number < 2048
SET IDENTITY_INSERT t OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO <tablename> DEFAULT VALUES;
```